# How to add logs to java agent where log level can be changed dynamically

Tags: java, logging, log4j, javaagents, apache-commons-logging

I need to add debug points in my javaagent. I am having my `premain` method in one class and `AgentClassFileTransformer` in another class. Since my organization use following approach which use `org.apache.commons.logging` package I also tried to use that method.

`private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(InstrumentingAgent.class);`

But, if I add only the **log4j.properties** file to the resource folder of the project, it prints the logs from the class with premain method.

But for the class which implements `ClassFileTransformer` it says no appenders can be found. But, again if I add the **commons-logging.properties** file to the same resources folder, then it'll print all the logs required in the console. (Even if I use the logger of type log4j as follows, it still says no appenders can be found for Transformer class)

**Commons-logging.properties**

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log = org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

Warning for Transformer class

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (InstrumentationClassTransformer).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

In my case I'll be adding on debug level logs in my agent. But when the agent run with a product it shouldn't print debug logs on the console. In terms of log4j I have read about setting the log level of the logger using `setLevel(Log.level)` method. But since I am using commons-logging's LogFactory it doesn't give any option to set the level also. So I would like to have some suggestions on how to get over this situation.

How can I get this to work? Is it something that can be achieved or do I need to change the logging mechanism?

**Update 1**

I have even added the package name, as mentioned by madhawa, but still it doesn't print logs of ClassFileTransformer.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.javaagent.instrumentation=DEBUG
```

Comment: besides what you wrote above: you might want to have a look at SLF4J which gives you the opportunity to combine many relevant different logging frameworks (commons logging, log4j, ...) into one single framework.

Comment: Can you show your current log4j.properties file?

Comment: I add it with Update 1

Comment: Add 
String confPath = "/path/to/log4j.properties";
PropertyConfigurator.configure(confPath);
to your main function and see if it is accepting the configurations

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't configure log4j.properties file correctly. Please add relevant packages and try again.

Comment: I add the package name as given in Update 1. But still it says no appenders can be found for org.javaagent.instrumentation.InstrumentationClassTransformer